# access: conditional formatting on report

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I have a report example two fields [Name1], [Name2]

what is the expression for conditional formatting on name1 to highlight when not = to name2?

Is it:

<>[Name2]

it is not working :(

Comment: avremel shalom! how are you? welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it two ways:

Select "Field Value", "Not Equal" and then type in "[Name2]"

or

Select "Expression" and type in "[Name1]<>[Name2]"